# Cant import random python

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I am having trouble importing random and randint in python

Here is the error I get when I "from random import randint"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Noah/Desktop/math.py", line 2, in <module>
    from random import randint
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 45, in <module>
    from math import log as _log, exp as _exp, pi as _pi, e as _e, ceil as _ceil
  File "/Users/Noah/Desktop/math.py", line 2, in <module>
    from random import randint
ImportError: cannot import name randint
```

and here is the error I get when "import random"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Noah/Desktop/math.py", line 2, in <module>
    import random
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 45, in <module>
    from math import log as _log, exp as _exp, pi as _pi, e as _e, ceil as _ceil
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

when I go to /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7 to check the files it has random.py random.pyc and random.pyo

python is using this as the path

```
>>> print random.__file__
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.pyc
```

Edit: I have no clue what could be happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traceback is relatively clear:

- you attempt to import `randint` from `random`;
- inside the python `random` module it attempts to import names from `math`;
- unfortunately, you chose to name one of your own modules in the working directory `math` as well and so it finds that first;
- when importing **your** `math`, it attempts to import `random` ... now you have an circular import ... and it fails.

#### Conclusion:

In Python 2, don't name your modules identically to core python modules ...

Answer (score 0):

In the same folder you have a file named **math.py**. You should delete this file, that is the reason it is not working.
My suggestion you may delete everything in that folder.

Comment: it should be a comment

Answer (score -1):

You should have save some file name random so the code is opening that file so try changing the name of that file